# ZFC applications of Shelah's creature forcing

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, forcing

Shelah's creature forcing is a very powerful method, with wide range of applications. The method also has some applications in ZFC, let's quote a few of them that I am aware of:

(1) In [A partition theorem](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0003163) Shelah proves a very general infinitary Ramsey theorem in ZFC, which is parallel to the Galvin-Prikry theorem and the Carlson-Simpson theorem.

(2) In [Partition theorems from creatures and idempotent ultrafilters](https://arxiv.org/abs/1005.2803), creature forcing is used to prove some Ramsey type theorems. As an application of their general method, new proof of Carlson-Simpson theorem is given. See also [Creature forcing and topological Ramsey spaces](https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.06402)

(3) In [Ramsey theorems for product of finite sets with submeasures](https://shelah.logic.at/files/95780/952.pdf) creature forcing is used to prove  a parametrized partition theorem on products of finite sets
equipped with submeasures. It improves the results of DiPrisco, Llopis,
and Todorcevic.

> **Question 1.** What other ZFC examples are available whose proofs is given by creature forcing?
>
> **Question 2.** Are there any applications of creature forcing in proving ZFC results, beyond those in Ramsey type theorems?

Comment: Creature forcing is the stuff of nightmares.

Comment: Science fiction - double feature -   Dr. X will build a creature...

Answer (score 10):

In *[Norms on possibilities II: more ccc ideals on $2^{\omega}$](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9703222)* (published version https://doi.org/10.1515/JAA.1997.103), Rosłanowski and Shelah use creature forcings to construct many ccc $\sigma$-ideals with properties similar to those of the ideal of meager / null sets, answering a question of Kunen.

Answer (score 7):

Also check: [MR3563073](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3563073) Dobrinen, Natasha Creature forcing and topological Ramsey spaces. Topology Appl. 213 (2016), 110–126; DOI: [10.1016/j.topol.2016.08.008](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.topol.2016.08.008), arXiv: [1509.06402](https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.06402).

Comment: and MR2146637  Goldstern, Martin; Shelah, Saharon
Clones from creatures.  
Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 357 (2005), no. 9, 3525–3551. (not exactly ZFC but a consequence of CH)

Comment: and MR1838340 Bartoszynski, Tomek; Shelah, Saharon
Strongly meager sets do not form an ideal.
J. Math. Log. 1 (2001), no. 1, 1–34.

Comment: On the importance of typesetting. The first comment read to me as if the paper's title was "Saharon Clones from Creatures".